# How do I convert currenecy based on a pre-determined conversion rate? (python)

Tags: python

I have over a thousand rows and in a a dataframe, and z dozen or so columns, including salary and currency.

I have a a .csv file that I need to use as the currency conversion rate, about 85 rows long, with two columns, one being origincountry and the other being exchangerate.

My task is convert all of these to the Australia exchange rate as determined in the file.

I am aware that I need to match the string of "origincountry" to "currency", then multiply that row's "salary" by the corresponding "exchangerate".

My question is, how do I do this? I've been searching for hours and have been unable to find an example of this. Any help or example would be great.

Edit: My apologies, I should have provided some sort of example. I am new to this site, and coding in general.

Below is one example of two columns from a data set.

df_salary

```
Salary               Currency
70000                USD
92000                USD
40000                EUR
400000               INR
200000               BRL
```

And here is a second set of columns.

CR

```
CurrencyCode     ExchangeRate
USD              1
INR              0.036
BRL              0.291
EUR              1.216
```

How do I multiply the Salary by the correct ExchangeRate?

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  "How do I write my program?" is far too broad fro Stack Overflow.

Comment: You might get better response if you post some of the code you've tried with some brief input data examples.

Answer (score 0):

As i can understand following is something you're looking for.
If you need exactness in answers , you should provide us  some data.

```
import numpy as np    
df['columnname'] = np.where(df['othercolumn'] == 'CertainString',df['columnname']*1000, df['columnname'])
```

try this one

```
df_salary['CompensationAmount'] = np.where(df_salary['CompensationCurrency'] == CR['originCountry'], df_salary['CompensationAmount'] * CR['exchangeRate'],df_salary['CompensationAmount'])
```

Comment: My apolgies, I definitely should come up with an example first

I have altered your code to be the following:
<!-- language: lang-none -->

df_salary['CompensationAmount'] = np.where(df_salary)['CompensationCurrency'] == CR['originCountry'], df_salary['CompensationAmount'] * CR['exchangeRate'])

Comment: Unfortunately I get the Error:

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects


Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to merge it and it automatically filled out the column alongside it with the correst currency conversions.

df_CRsalary_merge = pd.merge(left = df_salary, right = df_CR, left_on = "CompensationCurrency", right_on = 'originCountry', how = 'left')
df_CRsalary_mergedrop = df_CRsalary_merge.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis = 1 )

print(df_CRsalary_mergedrop)